# Synchronize sensor updates

Tags: android, rotation, android-sensors, synchronize, acceleration

I've been trying lately to synchronize sensor updates, especially getting values from TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR and TYPE_ACCELEROMETER as close as possible in time.

This is a complete program for showing what's making it hard for me to do so:

```
public class FusionTest extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager sensorManager = null;

    private Sensor rotSensor = null;
    private Sensor accSensor = null;

    private int rots = 0;
    private int accs = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        rotSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
        accSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        sensorManager.registerListener(this, rotSensor, 500 * 1000);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accSensor, 500 * 1000);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
            accs++;
            System.out.println("accs: "+accs+", rots: "+rots);
        }else if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR){
            rots++;
            System.out.println("accs: "+accs+", rots: "+rots);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) { }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, rotSensor);
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, accSensor);
    }

}
```

The purpose of this program is to see how often the sensors provide updates with their delay set. If I let this program run for exactly 50 seconds, this is the last line of the output:

```
05-21 19:37:01.431: D/FusionTest(26378): accs: 758, rots: 100
```

It seems like I get rotation vector updates with 500 ms delay but acceleration updates with about 66 ms delay. This is from the documentation of registerListener:

> rateUs --> The rate sensor events are delivered at. This is only a hint to the system. Events may be received faster or slower than the specified rate. Usually events are received faster. The value must be one of SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SENSOR_DELAY_UI, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, or SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST or, the desired delay between events in microseconds. Specifying the delay in microseconds only works from Android 2.3 (API level 9) onwards. For earlier releases, you must use one of the SENSOR_DELAY_* constants.

I'm targeting Android 4.4.2 so I should be able to specify the delay in microseconds. I understand that if I specify that the system is to deliver updates with 500 ms delay, it will only be a hint to the system. But the fact that the delay time is interpreted differently in the implementation of the rotation vector and the accelerometer makes it hard to synchronize the data. When I get the acceleration update at time t, I also want to get the rotation vector at time t, and vice versa. Is there a way do achieve this?

EDIT: The closest I can do at the moment is to choose the sensor that provides updates slowest, and then interpolate between the values of the other sensor to approximate the value of the slower sensor at the time i got a value from the first sensor. This is still not what i want but at least an improvement from just collecting unsynchronized data.